Select unique row and column entry from an nxn matrix
I have an n x n matrix, for sake of simplicity say n=5
Example:
{
{2, 3, 12, 19, 1},
{4, 23, 6, 8, 7},
{3, 22, 18, 5, 4},
{14, 11, 3, 8, 7},
{4, 12, 19, 13, 3}
}

Now I want to select 5 members from it so that all the members are from a unique column and row. In other words, no 2 members share the same column and row. (None of the 5 members can intersect Horizontally nor Vertically)
Two example:

Obvious diagonal one:  2, 23, 18, 8, 3

Say Swap the first 2 in columns:  3, 4, 18, 8, 3
....etc...
Now find ALL such sets.


Once we have the sets, see which one has the maximum sum!
Are there any Internal Mathematica functions that can find those sets.
P.S.
I suspect the method I used to swap the first 2 columns can be expanded above to get all: For example: Start with the diagonal, then get All sets of Permutations so they can be swapped around within various columns? ....

The selection rule is exactly the same as in the definition of matrix determinants, isn't it? Yes, the group of all permutations are generated by transpositions (swaps).

Great solution, Thanks! Reminder I want the final list with a Max sum!

Yes, I know. The variable maximalchoice contains the positions {row #, column #} in the matrix corresponding to the maximal choice.

Ahhhh right! Was wondering about that....I suppose if I want the maximum Product, I just replace the "Total" with "Times" ? Nope didn't work...! lol

You are right. All you have to do is replace Total[entries[#]]& by Times@@entries[#]&.This is because Total takes a single list as argument, but Times can take several arguments.

got it to work:   Grid[Sort[{Times @@ #, #} & /@ choices], Dividers -> All]

Can you tell me what this means?  (* {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}} *)  What are these sets?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

mat = {{2, 3, 12, 19, 1}, {4, 23, 6, 8, 7}, {3, 22, 18, 5, 4}, {14, 
   11, 3, 8, 7}, {4, 12, 19, 13, 3}}; mat // MatrixForm


entries[perm_List] := MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {mat, perm}];

maximalchoice = Transpose[{Range[Length[mat]],First[MaximalBy[
     Permutations[Range[Length[mat]]], Total[entries[#]] &]]}]

(* {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}} *)

Grid[mat, Background -> {None, None, # -> Green & /@ maximalchoice}]


Table of various choices:
choices = entries /@ Permutations[Range[Length[mat]]];
Grid[Sort[{Total[#], #} & /@ choices], Dividers -> All]



opMat = {{2, 3, 12, 19, 1}, {4, 23, 6, 8, 7}, {3, 22, 18, 5, 4}, {14, 
11, 3, 8, 7}, {4, 12, 19, 13, 3}};

Proceeding much as @vindobona and @A. Kato have done, but using the built-in  Permanent command to get the list of all determinant terms in a symbolic (5 x 5) matrix (5! terms), before substituting in the OP values.
A list of all terms in the determinant of a symbolic (5x5) matrix:
tmat5 = MapApply[List]@Table[Permanent[Array[a, {5, 5}]][[i]], {i, 1, 5!}];

  tmat5//Short 

  (* {{a[1,5],a[2,4],a[3,3],a[4,2],a[5,1]},
       <<118>>,
     {a[1,1],a[2,2],a[3,3],a[4,4],a[5,5]}} *)

Substituting the OP values
assoc5 = AssociationThread[Flatten[Array[a, {5, 5}]] -> Flatten[opMat]];

Maximum Sum
Max[Total /@ (tmat5 /. assoc5)]

With[{totals = Total /@ (tmat5 /. assoc5)}, 
    Extract[tmat5, Position[totals, Max[totals]]]]

% /. assoc5

(*
  81

  {{a[1, 4], a[2, 5], a[3, 2], a[4, 1], a[5, 3]}}

  {{19, 7, 22, 14, 19}}
*)

Minimum Sum
Min[Total /@ (tmat5 /. assoc5)]

With[{totals = Total /@ (tmat5 /. assoc5)}, Extract[tmat5, 
    Position[totals, Min[totals]]]]

% /. assoc5

(* 
   18

   {{a[1, 2], a[2, 1], a[3, 4], a[4, 3], a[5, 5]}}

   {{3, 4, 5, 3, 3}}
 *) 

Table of Values (OP Matrix)
(Remove //Short for full table)
SortBy[With[{values = tmat5 /. assoc5}, 
   Transpose[{Total /@ values, values}]], First] // Short

(*{
   {18,{3,4,5,3,3}},
   {20,{3,8,3,3,3}},
    <<116>>,
   {79,{19,23,4,14,19}},
   {81,{19,7,22,14,19}}
  } *)

A (5 x 5) matrix, of course, should have 5! terms in the determinant:
SortBy[With[{values = tmat5 /. assoc5}, Transpose[{Total /@ values, values}]], 
    First] // Length

(* 120 *)

Table of Values (Symbolic Matrix)
SortBy[With[{values = tmat5 /. assoc5}, 
   Transpose[{Total /@ values, tmat5}]], First] // Short


(* {
    {18,{a[1,2],a[2,1],a[3,4],a[4,3],a[5,5]}},
      <<118>>,
    {81,{a[1,4],a[2,5],a[3,2],a[4,1],a[5,3]}}} *)


Just another possibility:
mat = {{2, 3, 12, 19, 1}, {4, 23, 6, 8, 7}, {3, 22, 18, 5, 4}, 
       {14, 11, 3, 8, 7}, {4, 12, 19, 13, 3}};

max = First@
        MaximalBy[
          mat*PermutationMatrix@# & /@ Permutations@Range[5]
          , Total[#, 2] &, 1]


 {{0 , 0 , 0 , 19, 0}
, {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 7}
, {0 , 22, 0 , 0 , 0}
, {14, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0}
, {0 , 0 , 19, 0 , 0}}


positions = Keys@Most@ArrayRules@max


{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}}


Of course. They are the positions of the nonzero  elements in the max matrix. By knowing the positions you can locate them in the original matrix. You could also try to execute the ArrayRules@max in order to see the keys and values together..

Thanks this is amazing! what if i wanted max(product)....i replaced the "Total" with "Times" but I think it dopesn't operate with the matrix and does not take a second parameter.

@Steve237 For max(product) one can use MaximalBy[mat*PermutationMatrix@# & /@ Permutations@Range[5], Times @@ Total[#, 1] &]

Why are we still "Total"ing....if we just want the Product , wouldn't "Times" suffice alone?

Total is applied at level 1 (rows) and the results are multiplied(Times) afterwards

Using the Resource Function MaximizeOverPermutations, which works even for large matrices by offering a Monte-Carlo search option:
A = {{2, 3, 12, 19, 1}, {4, 23, 6, 8, 7}, {3, 22, 18, 5, 4}, {14, 11, 3, 8, 7}, {4, 12, 19, 13, 3}};
f[p_] := Total[MapThread[Part, {A, p}]]

M = ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"];
M[f, 5]
(*    {{{4, 5, 2, 1, 3}}, 81}    *)

Let's try it for a 20×20 matrix, for which exhaustive searching is impossible:
SeedRandom[1234];
A = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, {20, 20}];
f[p_] := Total[MapThread[Part, {A, p}]]

M[f, 20, Method -> {"MonteCarlo",
                    "Iterations" -> 10^6,
                    "AnnealingParameter" -> 0.1}]
(*    {{{16, 9, 1, 7, 10, 5, 20, 15, 8, 11, 18, 12, 4, 6, 2, 14, 19, 17, 13, 3}}, 1849.}    *)

I suspect that this is the global maximum but haven't proven it.
In the same way, we can find the permutation that minimizes the sum:
M[-f[#] &, 20, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "Iterations" -> 10^6, "AnnealingParameter" -> 0.1}]
(*    {{{6, 4, 20, 15, 16, 17, 12, 3, 10, 5, 11, 14, 9, 7, 1, 8, 13, 2, 19, 18}}, -118.}    *)

which I also supposed to be globally optimal.

Edit with more background
This can be seen as an assignment problem, where we want to maximize the edge weight of a matching of a bipartite graph.
To create our bipartite graph, we can interpret each row as a person, and each column as a job type. The matrix entries correspond to the effectiveness of each person doing each job type. Only one person can be doing a given job at a time.
We then use FindIndependentEdgeSets (which superseded MaximalBipartiteMatching in v10) to find the maximal matching of the graph.
So we start by first making our two independent vertex sets that make up the bipartite graph
mat = {{2, 3, 12, 19, 1}, {4, 23, 6, 8, 7}, {3, 22, 18, 5, 4}, {14, 
    11, 3, 8, 7}, {4, 12, 19, 13, 3}};
n = Length@mat;

people = Array[p, n];
jobs = Array[j, n];

and create our bipartite graph, using mat as the edge weights
edges = Flatten@Outer[DirectedEdge, people, jobs];
weights = Flatten@mat;

gr = Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> weights]


And find the job assignment that maximizes total effectiveness:
result = List @@@ FindIndependentEdgeSet[gr]
(* {{p[1], j[4]}, {p[4], j[1]}, {p[3], j[2]}, {p[5], j[3]}, {p[2], j[5]}} *)

Convert to matrix indices, and calculate the total weight:
indices = Cases[result, {p[x_], j[y_]} -> {x, y}, Infinity];
indices = SortBy[indices,First];

resultWeights = Apply[Part[mat, ##] &, indices, {1}]
max1 = Total[resultWeights]

(*{19, 14, 22, 19, 7}*)

(*81*)


Putting this all together as a function

findMaximalJobAssignment[mat_] := 
 Module[{n, people, jobs, edges, weights, gr, result, indices, 
   resultWeights},

  n = Length@mat;
  
  people = Array[p, n];
  jobs = Array[j, n];
  
  edges = Flatten@Outer[DirectedEdge, people, jobs];
  weights = Flatten@mat;
  
  gr = Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> weights];
  
  result = List @@@ FindIndependentEdgeSet[gr];
  indices = Cases[result, {p[x_], j[y_]} -> {x, y}, Infinity];
  indices = SortBy[indices, First];

  resultWeights = Apply[Part[mat, ##] &, indices, {1}];
  
  {Total@resultWeights, resultWeights}
  
  ]

and using @A. Kato's answer as validation:
entries[mat_, perm_List] := MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {mat, perm}];
kato[mat_] := Module[{maximalchoice, resultWeights},
  maximalchoice = 
   Transpose[{Range[Length[mat]], 
     First[MaximalBy[Permutations[Range[Length[mat]]], 
       Total[entries[mat, #]] &]]}];
  
  resultWeights = Apply[Part[mat, ##] &, maximalchoice, {1}];
  {Total[resultWeights], resultWeights}
  ]

We see they agree, at least as far as the value of the maximum sum is concerned (sometimes when there's a tie in two different paths for the maximum sum they pick different paths, but that doesn't matter if all we want is the maximum sum).

And @@ Table[
  n = RandomInteger[{3, 7}];
  m = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {n, n}];
  First@kato[m] == First@findMaximalJobAssignment[m]
  , 100]

(*True*)


Note this is faster for larger matrices:
matBig = RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {9, 9}];
findMaximalJobAssignment[matBig] // AbsoluteTiming
kato[matBig] // AbsoluteTiming


(*
{0.000503,{235,{22,23,25,25,26,27,29,29,29}}}

{2.26218,{235,{22,23,25,25,26,27,29,29,29}}}
*)

Or using @Roman's example of a big matrix, it finishes in about 0.001 s:
 SeedRandom[1234];
matVeryBig = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, {20, 20}];
findMaximalJobAssignment[matVeryBig]//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000988, {1849, {86, 98, 88, 91, 89, 83, 95, 98, 85, 95, 99, 95, 93,
    89, 95, 96, 87, 99, 91, 97}}} *)

Also, FWIW, note the minimum sum can be calculated by negating the input matrix (and negating the output)
-findMaximalJobAssignment[-mat]

(*{18, {3, 4, 5, 3, 3}}*)


Small add-on
This is just a slightly cleaner implementation of findMaximalJobAssignment using CompleteGraph:
findMaximalJobAssignment[mat_] := 
 Module[{n, weights, g, result, indices, resultWeights},

  n = Length@mat;
  weights = Flatten@mat;

  g = CompleteGraph[{n, n}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
    EdgeWeight -> weights];
  
  result = List @@@ FindIndependentEdgeSet[g];
  indices = Mod[result, n, 1];
  indices = SortBy[indices, First];
  
  resultWeights = Part[mat, ##] & @@@ indices;
  {Total@resultWeights, resultWeights}
  
  ]



Very nice! Clearly MaximizeOverPermutations should only be used on NP-hard problems, and for others we should look for smart algorithms.

@Roman We are in luck! The assignment problem can be calculated in  polynomial time (I have no idea what algorithms FindIndependentEdgeSet uses however)
